# Accessing MySQL database through SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, mysql, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

At the moment I can access a MySQL database by SSHing in terminal.
This prompts me for a passphrase for a key

```
ssh test-db01.somedomain.com

Enter passphrase for key '/Users/yourname/.ssh/path/to/key':
```

which I enter.

At this point I am in the remote host and can simply type

```
mysql

> SELECT * FROM users;
> ...
```

and mess around in the console.

This can be a bit cumbersome for me, and I want to connect up my SQL GUI (by tunnelling) so I can visualise all my records and stuff (I am using VSCode database tool), so it looks like this:

[image]

I have a bunch of config and keys corresponding to this host in my `~/.ssh` folder.

The host I enter is the same one when I SSH in terminal.

That is, `test-db01.somedomain.com`.

As you can see I get a `SSH error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`.

Any ideas what I can try here?

Comment: Do you have a jumphost or anything of that sort configured in ~/.ssh/config?

Comment: So have you explicitly allowed root access in the MySQL configuration? It’s not typically allowed. You also have defined 127.0.0.1 as the host?

Comment: I also tried my username. The one I automatically sign is as when I type `mysql`

Comment: I'm not sure what a jumphost. I have a config as follows:

Comment: Host test-db03.mydomain.ie
  User dennis.callanan
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my.name.luaws.stage02
  ProxyJump dennis.callanan@test-gw01.mydomain.ie